# Hidden database files in application folder after installation

Tags: vb.net

I am newbie to vb.net  I have tested a few applications downloaded from net.  They are surely database applications but when I checked in the folder where the application is installed, there is no database (no mdb, sdf etc.) 
When I install my application, my databases are always in the folder.

What is the trick to make them invisible but they should still work.

Thanks

Comment: Databases could not be invisible! Which kind of databases are those app using? MySql? MS-SQL? Oracle? SQLite? Database files are not necessary meant to stay in app folder...

Answer (score 1):

If the applications are using databases files such as Access or SQLite, then they are probably storing them in a user-specific directory, such as C:\Users\MyUser\My Documents\MyApplication\MyDatabase.mdb, instead of in the application directory.

This allows the applications to keep different databases for each user that logs onto the machine.